# Matplotlib throw errors and doesn't work when I try to import it

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm a newbie in programming and python (only 30 days). I've installed `Anaconda` and working in the `Spyder IDE`. Everything was going fine and have been adding packages as necessary while I was learning different things until now. Now, I'm getting an error when I'm trying to import `Matplotlib`. Can anyone advise me what to do in simple terms, please?

> Error processing line 1 of
>   C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-3.1.2-py3.7-nspkg.pth:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
>         exec(line)
>       File "", line 1, in 
>       File "", line 580, in module_from_spec   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
>   'loader'
>
> Remainder of file ignored

Comment: I just remembered that I also installed ArcGIS Pro and part of that also installs Matplotlib. I checked that the ArcGIS Pro installs different versions of Python and Matplotlib. for example when I do conda list I see Python 3.7.3 and Matplotlib 3.1.2 but  ArcGIS installed Python 3.6.8 and Matplotlib 3.0.3. I am wondering if this is what caused the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your package uninstall did not finish properly and something of that google package has been left behind.

You need to either move some of your source files at correct destination or uninstall anaconda and reinstall again.